# System Monitor fails to launch

Tags: 15.10, system-monitor

Ubuntu 15.10, System Monitor doesn't launch. Trying to launch from terminal gets this error:

```
gnome-system-monitor: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11VariantTypeD1Ev
```

Comment: Can you tell me the contents of the directory `/etc/ls.so.conf.d`, and if it exists, the contents of he file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf`

Comment: Thanks!  quin@quin-ubuntu:~$ ls /etc/ld.so.conf.d
fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  libc.conf
i386-linux-gnu.conf             x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf          x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf
LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf            x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf = /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1

Answer (score 6):

K - You are loading a library specific to VMWare, so I assume that you need to use that program, like I do.

1st:  Edit `/usr/bin/vmware` and add the line

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

anywhere around the line which says `set -e`.

If you use VMPlayer, do the same for `/usr/bin/vmplayer`

Remove the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf`

Execute the command `sudo ldconfig`

All should work properly at this point.

Comment: Yep, you're the man of the hour!  Worked great for VMPlayer.